# Marlin inline void gcode_M400()

Tags: marlin

Can someone show me how to add Lines to Marlin 1.1.8 ?
I want to change the M400 command.
In a kind like that:

```
M400 () { move Z + 5 if not Z MAX; Home X; printbed on MAX LENGHT}.
```

This coud be ported to pause and abort.

Comment: That should be doable, but what you want is not possible if the printer hasn't been homed yet. The printer should be homed first, else Z is unknown. Note that it not smart to let known commands do something different than default. I think in version 1.1.8, the printer will not go over the limits, so no need to check for Z max. Programmatically, you need to send (`G28`), `G91`, `G1 Z5 F1000`, `G90`, `G1 X0 Ymax` where Ymax needs to receive the max set in the firmware first.

Comment: M400 is the final command print finished so all axes are homed long before.
But i dont know how to add lines of code to this function.
I tried but nothing worked :(

Comment: Not necessarily, motors can be disabled, there is no guarantee the printer is homed. Maybe in your case yes, but if you override a command, you should make it generic. Maybe you could add to the question why you want to do this, this seems exactly something for an end G-code script?

Comment: The End Gcode is befor M400 method of marlin so FW will execude commands after the End Gcode from slicer so i need help to add lines of code to the method of m400 in marlin firmeware